# Sending IR signals to Robosapien using Arduino

Tags: arduino, infrared, reverse-engineering

I am trying to send commands to a Robosapien (first generation) using an IR LED hooked up to an Arduino. I have seen web pages on attaching a microcontroller directly to the toy, but what I want to do is just send commands via IR.

I found an article by K. Smith that mentioned that the IR commands sent by the Robosapien remote take the following form:

To send the hex code `85`:

> The IRout signal is held high until a signal is sent. Then a string of
>   five zeros is sent to signify a command is coming. Then the hex code
>   is sent but instead of sending a ‘1’ a ‘1110’ is sent and rather than
>   a ‘0’ a ‘10’ is sent. So $85 looks like this:

```
Binary:     1    0  0  0  0  1    0  1
Robosapien: 1110 10 10 10 10 1110 10 1110
```

So I tried the code below:

```
int bitTime=833; 
int IROut =  4; 

// The setup() method runs once, when the sketch starts

void setup()   {                
  // initialize the IR digital pin as an output:
  pinMode(IROut, OUTPUT);      

  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void test()
{
  // output high
  digitalWrite(IROut,HIGH);
  delay(1000);

  // 5 zeros
  digitalWrite(IROut,LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(bitTime);
  digitalWrite(IROut,HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(bitTime);
  digitalWrite(IROut,LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(bitTime);
  digitalWrite(IROut,HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(bitTime);
  digitalWrite(IROut,LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(bitTime);
  digitalWrite(IROut,HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(bitTime);
  digitalWrite(IROut,LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(bitTime);
  digitalWrite(IROut,HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(bitTime);
  digitalWrite(IROut,LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(bitTime);

  // send 1110 10 10 10 1110 10 1110

  // 1110
  digitalWrite(IROut,HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(3*bitTime);
  digitalWrite(IROut,LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(bitTime);
  // 10
  digitalWrite(IROut,HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(bitTime);
  digitalWrite(IROut,LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(bitTime);
  // 10
  digitalWrite(IROut,HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(bitTime);
  digitalWrite(IROut,LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(bitTime);
  // 10
  digitalWrite(IROut,HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(bitTime);
  digitalWrite(IROut,LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(bitTime);
  // 1110
  digitalWrite(IROut,HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(3*bitTime);
  digitalWrite(IROut,LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(bitTime);
  // 10
  digitalWrite(IROut,HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(bitTime);
  digitalWrite(IROut,LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(bitTime);
  // 1110
  digitalWrite(IROut,HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(3*bitTime);
  digitalWrite(IROut,LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(bitTime);

   // output high
  digitalWrite(IROut,HIGH);
  delay(1000);
}

void loop()                     
{ 
  test();
}
```

But unfortunately I am not getting any response from the Robosapien. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Uhm... are you using external components to modulate the IR signal over the 39.something KHz carrier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit time of 833 µs implies a data rate of 1200 bps. I don't know anything about Robosapien, but my first thought is that this signal is possibly meant to be the keying (envelope) imposed on a higher-frequency (e.g., 38 kHz) IR carrier signal.

Can you provide a link to the K. Smith article for reference?

Comment: Precisely. Robosapien AFAIR (I've played with that thing years ago) asks for a 1200 bps signal over a 39.2 KHz carrier.

Comment: Thanks, Dave. Here is the link to the article: http://www.docstoc.com/docs/27902404/Robosapien-Project

Comment: Dave, you've pointed me in the right direction. This is all new stuff to me - I'll look into how to generate the carrier signal.